# Registration on the app failed (MAUI/Comet)

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Code: https://github.com/ToadallyAwesome2/ComettTest

So I am using Maui/Comet. I just want to run a sample project, but I get this error:

```
DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] 
AppxManifest.xml(33,27): error 0x80070003: Cannot install or update 
package BF12F2F8-C129-4401-821A-69268F23ED72_9zz4h110yvjzm because the
 splash screen image [appiconfgSplashScreen.png] cannot be located. 
Verify that the package contains an image that can be used as a splash
 screen for the application, and that the package manifest points to 
the correct location in the package where this splash screen image can
 be found.
```

Anyone knows what I can do? I tried making an assets folder with that png, but it didnt work.

UPDATE
Did what Gerard Versluis recommended and got the following error:

```
DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80080204] error 0xC00CE020:
 App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per 
schema: Line 26, Column 8, Reason: Het vereiste kenmerk 
Square150x150Logo ontbreekt.    CometApp1
```

translation: The required attribute Square150x150Logo is missing.
I notice that it keeps asking for the Square150x150Logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of change in one of the previews. Long story short; we used to have an Assets folder for the Windows app, but not anymore. Since it's all in preview there wasn't a concern for backwards compatibility, but now this could occur.

It happens because you probably started a project earlier, with older templates, and are now trying to build against new preview bits. So in the templates the Assets folder is still mentioned, but is no long there.

The steps to take are also described in the [preview 13 migration guide](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-to-Preview-13).

1. Go into the `Platforms\Windows` folder and open the `Package.appxmanifest` file. Right-click > Open With... and choose the XML editor
2. Remove all references to `Assets\`
3. Double-check your `App.xaml` file to see if there is a `windows:Application.ImageDirectory` attribute on the `Application` node. If so, remove it. For example:

```xml
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.WindowsSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             windows:Application.ImageDirectory="Assets"
             x:Class="WeatherTwentyOne.App">
```

should now be

```xml
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WeatherTwentyOne.App">
```

After that, it should work again!

To make sure it doesn't happen again, make sure that you have the latest templates by running `dotnet new -i Microsoft.Maui.Templates` which should get you the latest templates that do not reference `Assets` anymore.

Comment: Hi Gerard, thank you for your answer! Ah got it, so due to a change it asks for the assets folder but it doesnt exsists. I tried your solution, but I still cant get it to work,It keeps asking for the assets stuff.  If you want to have a better look at my code, I have pushed it to github, https://github.com/ToadallyAwesome2/ComettTest

Comment: You forgot one :)  https://github.com/ToadallyAwesome2/ComettTest/blob/main/CometApp1/CometApp1/Platforms/Windows/Package.appxmanifest#L17

Comment: ah gotcha, thought I deleted them all xD
but still i get the new error message Het vereiste kenmerk 
Square150x150Logo ontbreekt. 

Just a thought: its not possible to give it a null value or something? Or should I make that Square150x150Logo?

Comment: Ha lekker Nederlands! ;) Hm that's strange. I know more improvements are coming to this area. Maybe the Comet templates need an update for this as well. I think you'll need that at least if you want to make it show up nicely everywhere in Windows. If not, or not now, you might be able to remove the entry altogether, not sure

Comment: Zeker weten :)
Aha yeah everything is still quite new. Atm I am also talking in the discord of Comet with Clansey about it, hope we can fix this "simple" problem. I will keep you up to date.

Still thanks for the help tho, I will keep trying :D!!!

Answer (score 0):

this was the only solution than worked for me:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/mauiapp-cannot-run-on-windows/1670999
Pasted below:

Upgrading the maui templates using
dotnet new --install Microsoft.Maui.Templates::6.0.200-preview.13.2865
solves this issue when creating a new MAUI App.

It would be nice, if the process of upgrading VS could include updating the MAUI templates or maybe warn about the need to manually update

In case of an existing MAUI App project - these changes worked for me:

- remove all references to the ‘Assets\’ subfolder from the Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest file
- add a line about raw assets to the .csproj file in the ItemGroup that contains the MauiIcon, MauiSplashScreen, MauiImage, MauiFont tags:

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
     ...
     <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
     <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
   </ItemGroup>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A variation of this error occurs when trying to run the default Maui project in Visual Studio.

```
DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073D1F]
```

If you happen to be hosting your project code on the network rather than on your local machine...

> Due to Windows platform restrictions, registering the app residing on network share is not supported. A potential workaround (besides moving the whole project to local storage) **is to redirect build outputs to local disk** (**Open project properties and change output path in “Build” settings**) (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/dep0700-registration-of-the-app-failed-error-when/1181309)

Answer (score -1):

delete your .vs/obj/bin/.csproj/.sln, and then dotnet new maui --force right inside that same folder. that fixed this issue for me, and this randomly happened to, but i think it was due to me updating some workloads. im also sure my project template was still on preview 9 lol. its always best to be on the latest template for each preview.

EDIT: if you modified your App.xaml/App.xaml.cs and/or MainPage.xaml/MainPage.xaml.cs, youre gonna need to save those so you can put them back. dotnet new maui will need to overwrite some things. unless you delete them, but theyre just things generated by the template. anything generated that you have modified, will need to be saved and updated.